# SQL: Compare each record of column with a range of values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL query which returns data as listed in table1. I want to compare the column table1.Count with table2.Count_Range. The range in which the Count value falls in its relevant Value column should be returned.

table1:

```
Time               Count
2014/02/24 00:00   23.3
2014/02/24 01:00   43.1
2014/02/24 02:00   93.5
2014/02/24 03:00   123.9
2014/02/24 04:00   173.0
2014/02/24 05:00   223.7
...
...
```

table2:

```
Count_Range   Value
10            1
20            2
30            3
40            4
50            5
...
...
```

For eg. at 00:00 the value is 23.3, from table2 it falls in the range between 20 and 30 so the value returned should be 2. Similarly for 01:00 the value returned should be 4.

The final table should be like below

Proposed output table3:

```
Time               Count   Value
2014/02/24 00:00   23.3    2
2014/02/24 01:00   43.1    4
2014/02/24 02:00   93.5    ...
2014/02/24 03:00   123.9   ...
2014/02/24 04:00   173.0   ...
2014/02/24 05:00   223.7   ...
```

Thanks to all in advance... btw this is my first question in this forum, in fact first for any forum on earth!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select top 1 t2.value
        from table2 t2
        where t2.count_range < t1."count"
        order by t2.count_range desc
      ) as value
from table1 t1;
```

Alternatively, SQL Server offers the `apply` keyword for this sort of thing:

```
select t1.*, t2.value
from table1 t1 cross apply
     (select top 1 t2.value
        from table2 t2
        where t2.count_range < t1."count"
        order by t2.count_range desc
      ) t2;
```

I prefer the first method because it is standard SQL (apart from the `top` keyword).

Comment: Thanks Gordon (and all others) for your help. I went with the first solution provided by Gordon. Just a minor change I did, i made the comparison as <= so that if the counts are equal, for eg. 40 in table2 and 40 in table1 it was taking the value as 3, now it takes 4. Thanks a lot again!!

Answer (score 0):

Another to do this is to first break the Count Range column into a low value and high value of each range:

`Low     High    Value
0        9        0
10       19       1
20       29       2
30       39       3
40       49       4
50       59       5
...     ...     ...`

And then using the following query:

SELECT Table1.Count, Table2.Value 
  FROM Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 
          ON Table1.Count >= Table2.LowRange 
             AND Table1.Count <= Table2.HighRange;

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple subquery to achieve this:

```
SELECT *, 
(SELECT MAX(value) FROM table2 WHERE Count_Range <= table1.Count) AS VALUE 
FROM table1
```

In your existing table 2, you would also have to add a row for range 0 to 10.

See [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec6b2/1) (note that table2 only contains the first 11 rows to show how it works)